# aws_network_acl doesn't support "Type"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

When I'm creating a Network ACL for AWS in Terraform I'm not able to configure the field "Type"

However if you configure the ACL via Portal the field type can be configured accordingly.

[aws nacl ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kU6V5.png)

Comment: Please add the terraform code you have to the question. Do not use screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

The `Type` field on the web console is just an easy way to select pre-configured combinations of protocols and ports. This field is not there in terraform templates, and you can simply specify the protocol and port separately as shown in @marcincuber's answer. It's the same in [AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-networkaclentry.html) as well.

Answer (score 0):

The type field is "automatically defined" based on the information you use for the port/protocol.

For example, try to create a rule for port 25/tcp.

After you apply and the rule is created, the type will automatically be set to "SMTP(25)".

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for the following terraform resources that support protocol argument:

```
resource "aws_network_acl" "bar" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.foo.id
}

resource "aws_network_acl_rule" "bar" {
  network_acl_id = aws_network_acl.bar.id
  rule_number    = 200
  egress         = false
  protocol       = "tcp"
  rule_action    = "allow"
  cidr_block     = aws_vpc.foo.cidr_block
  from_port      = 22
  to_port        = 22
}
```

The example was takes from https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/network_acl_rule

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question,  it looks like he is wondering why "aws_network_acl" doesn't have a "type" parameter while the aws console does.

Comment: I think it clearly answers the question. aws_network_acl doesn't support such a parameter because it is set at aws_network_acl_rule level.